# After Uploading video on Youtube using Java Script API I am unable to make it public

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, youtube, youtube-api, google-developers-console

It works but I want To make it Public please help me with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YouTube Videos uploaded by applications which has not completed the verified will be uploaded to private.

If you want to be able to upload public videos you will need to go through the [verification process](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification) on Google Cloud console.   It can take a bit of time to  go though the process.

Make sure you have set up the following

- completely fill out the consent screen
- register your domain on search console
- depending upon which scope you are requesting you may need to create a video showing your app in action.

[What you need to know about Google verification in 2021.](https://youtu.be/lzIuNmNX9N8)

Comment: I am Using Apps script should I need to verify and if yes than how to do.I am unable to understand the upward verification process.

Comment: If you want to publish public videos using the YouTube API you have to verify your application even app script.   It is a limitation in the YouTube API unverified apps cant upload public videos only private ones.  The video i linked goes through the application verification process, and the description contains all of the links on how to go through the process.

Comment: One more thing after verification can I schedule videos using the API?

Comment: not as far as i know but you might want to try going though the documentation.

Comment: Can you add a link to the documentation.

Comment: You could also have searched for it you know?  [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/)

Comment: Thanks for your Help now it is working and if I need again your help from where I can contact you?

Comment: Check my profile there are a bunch of contact points in there.   But asking questions here works i monitor most of the Google related tags

Answer (score 2):

All videos uploaded via the videos.insert endpoint from unverified API projects created after 28 July 2020 will be restricted to private viewing mode. To lift this restriction, each API project must undergo an audit to verify compliance with the Terms of Service. Please see the API Revision History for more details.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert

Answer (score -1):

try deleting it and then post it again by making it public while posting .